# Writing specific sections from txt file to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file of online physician recommendations. In this file, there are questions asked by each patient and answers given by the physician. In addition, the question id and links are also shared. I'm focusing only on certain headers from a text file and I want to export these fields to a pandas dataframe. txt file as below:

```
Description Q. What should I do to get glowing fair skin?
        
Dialogue 
Patient: Hi doctor, My face and body color are different. My face is getting dark and black day-by-day. What should I do to increase my fairness and get glowing skin? Shall I use some night cream? 
Doctor: Hi. I have read your problem carefully. What is your nature of work? Will you get exposed to sunlight? ... Take care. 
    
id=13585 https://www.icliniq.com/qa/migraine-headaches/how-can-i-cure-one-sided-headache-with-vomiting
    
Description Q. How can I cure one sided headache with vomiting?
    
Dialogue
Patient: Hi doctor, I have one side headache. How to cure it? Will you please give your suggestion? During maigrane headache, I have vomiting. 
Doctor: Hello. You seem to be suffering from migraine.   
    
id=13586 https://www.icliniq.com/qa/diarrhea/what-is-causing-diarrhea-after-eating-a-spicy-dish
```

From this file, I only want to get the words of the patients and the answers of the doctors. Output Like this :

```
    Patient                                             Doctor
0   I am 26 years old. I just found out that I hav...   Hi. For further information consult a ...
1   I am a 46 year old male. My weight is 75 kg an...   Hi. I understand your problem. Revert ... 
2   Since five days, I am having non-radiating che...   ECG and chest x-ray. For further infor...
```

I want to delete other parts in text (description and id lines). I just want to keep the patient and doctor sections in the dataframe. How can I do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to check out [ask] and how to create a [mre] to help create questions that are likely to receive good answers! Notice that your included image is all text (under [ask] you'll see that images should only be used in the rarest of circumstances) and under [mre] you'll see that "i have a complex txt file" is not enough for us help. Also note that asking for a solution without showing a meaningful attempt often results in your question going unanswered. Please edit the post with your changes once you've visited those links!

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex for matching pattern of dialouges and then you can trim them i wrote a little bit messy code for instance

```py
import re
text = """Description Q. What should I do to get glowing fair skin?
        
Dialogue 
Patient: Hi doctor, My face and body color are different. My face is getting dark and black day-by-day. What should I do to increase my fairness and get glowing skin? Shall I use some night cream? 
Doctor: Hi. I have read your problem carefully. What is your nature of work? Will you get exposed to sunlight? ... Take care. 
    
id=13585 https://www.icliniq.com/qa/migraine-headaches/how-can-i-cure-one-sided-headache-with-vomiting
    
Description Q. How can I cure one sided headache with vomiting?
    
Dialogue
Patient: Hi doctor, I have one side headache. How to cure it? Will you please give your suggestion? During maigrane headache, I have vomiting. 
Doctor: Hello. You seem to be suffering from migraine.   
    
id=13586 https://www.icliniq.com/qa/diarrhea/what-is-causing-diarrhea-after-eating-a-spicy-dish"""

matchespatient = re.finditer("Patient: (.*?)\n", text, re.DOTALL)
matchesdoctor = re.finditer("Doctor: (.*?)\n", text, re.DOTALL)

zip_object = zip(matchespatient, matchesdoctor)
cnt = 0

print("\tPatient\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDoctor")
for i,j in zip_object:
    pat = i.group(0)[9:-1]
    doc = j.group(0)[8:-1]
    print(f"{cnt}\t{pat[:46]}...\t{doc[:46]}...")
    cnt+=1
```

output of this code is like this

```
        Patient                                                 Doctor
0       Hi doctor, My face and body color are differen...       Hi. I have read your problem carefully. What i...
1       Hi doctor, I have one side headache. How to cu...       Hello. You seem to be suffering from migraine....
```